# How to produce the ILU0 or ILUT as stand-alone procedures on sparse matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

*Mathematica* uses the ILU0 procedures automatically to precondition large sparse linear systems; e.g.

```
LinearSolve[mat, rhs, Method -> {Krylov, Preconditioner -> ILU0}]; // Timing
```

I wish to have the incomplete factorization of the large sparse matrix A in a standalone procedure.

I would be grateful if someone could give some tips or written code to provide the ILU0 or ILUT approximate inverses as standalone procedures.

Comment: ``?*`*ILU*`` will reveal which internal functions do this.  You might want to experiment with them and figure out their calling syntax.

Comment: There was [some discussion on this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Dec/msg00050.html) in MathGroup, but nothing too concrete showed up.

Comment: @Szabolcs: it seems to suffice just giving the `SparseArray[]` object to ``SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU[] ``; one can then set the `Method` option to either `"ILU0"` or `"ILUT"` as needed. One can then use `LowerTriangularize[]` and `UpperTriangularize[]` to extract the needed factors from the compressed `SparseArray[]` representation.

Comment: @J.M. Can you post that as an answer?  I'm not familiar enough with ILU.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Maybe after some more experimentation; it seems I got lucky with my initial examples, and extracting the factors isn't as simple as I thought it was. But the output of ``SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU[] `` is similar to the output of `LUDecomposition[]` as expected: the compressed matrix where the $\mathbf L$ and $\mathbf U$ factors are packed, and a permutation matrix represented as an integer permutation...

Comment: Consider the following sparse matrix: n = 10000;
A = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 120}] -> -2., Band[{950, 1}] -> -1., 
   Band[{1, 1}] -> 20., Band[{1, 100}] -> 2., 
   Band[{6, 800}] -> 1.1}, {n, n}, 0.]  How do you obtain its ILU0 factorization? I need it as a stand alone output to then apply it whereever I need. I will be grateful if anyone respond.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to do it:

```
dim = 5;
s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -2., {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 
     1.}, {dim, dim}, 0.];
s[[1, All]] = s[[-1, All]] = 0.;
s[[1, 1]] = s[[-1, -1]] = 1.;
f = ConstantArray[0., {dim}];
f[[1]] = 0.; f[[-1]] = 1.;

LinearSolve[s, f]
{0.`, 0.25`, 0.5`, 0.75`, 1.`}
```

Now, we can use:

```
res = SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU[s]
```

And then:

```
SparseArray`SparseMatrixApplyILU[res, f]
{0.`, 0.24999999999999997`, 0.49999999999999994`, \
0.7499999999999999`, 1.`}

res[[1]] // Normal
{{1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {1.`, -2.`, 1.`, 0.`, 
  0.`}, {0.`, -0.5`, -1.5`, 1.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 
  0.`, -0.6666666666666666`, -1.3333333333333335`, 1.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 
  0.`, 0.`, 1.`}}
```

Also,

```
Options[SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU]
{SparseArray`FillIn -> Automatic, Method -> "ILUT", 
 SparseArray`PermutationTolerance -> Automatic, Tolerance -> Automatic}
SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU[s, Method -> "ILUTP"]
```

Or,

```
res2 = SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU[LowerTriangularize[s]]
```

And as a preconditioner:

```
pf = With[{pm = res2},
  Function[arg,
   SparseArray`SparseMatrixApplyILU[pm, arg]
   ]]

LinearSolve[s, f, Method -> {"Krylov", "Preconditioner" -> pf}]
{0.`, 0.25000000000000006`, 0.5000000000000001`, 0.7500000000000001`, \
1.`}
```

If you think this should be documented, extended etc. then you should write a comment about that to the support at wolfram only if enough people request this type of functionality will be done. Maybe.

Comment: Finally… ;) For reference, is there a demo showing how the original matrix can be reconstituted from the triangular factors?